# Google Analytics: Should I Use The Multiple Domains Option?

Tags: google-analytics

Sorry for the naive question:

I have a website with a ".com.au" TLD and I have another domain with a ".com" TLD which redirects all its traffic to the ".com.au" site.

Should I be using the multiple domains option on Google Analytics?

Comment: Why would you want to setup analytics on the website that "redirects" your traffic? Assuming that its a htaccess/any other server side redirect, your google analytics javascript snippet will never fire.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As hinted by the commenter, there is no need for multiple domain tracking if you're only tracking one of the domain.

I would suggest to use an HTTP 301 redirect (moved permanently), which will ensure :
* the .com does not get tracked as a referring website to the .com.au (original referrer should be shown instead).
* search engines will stop indexing the .com and send traffic directly to the .com.au.